# RestTemplate mapping to object

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to use RestTemplate to call a webservice, currently I am using the Object type rather than a concrete user defined one which is what I want to do.

Currently the response from the web service is:

```
{Locales=[{Code=ar-AE, Name=العربية (الإمارات العربية المتحدة)}, {Code=az-AZ, Name=Azərbaycan­ılı (Azərbaycan)}, {Code=bg-BG, Name=български (България)}]}
```

I am currently doing this:

```
Object locales = restTemplate.getForObject(localeUrl, Object.class, apiKey);
```

which is I want to be able to map it to a class that I have defined, but not sure how my class should be laid out, my class currently looks like this:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Locales")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Locales {
    private List<Locale> Locales = new ArrayList<>();

    private Locales(){};

    public List<Locale> getLocales() {
        return Locales;
    }

    public void setLocales(ArrayList<Locale> newLocales) {
        this.Locales = newLocales;
    }
}

@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Locale {
    private String Code;
    private String Name;

    private Locale(){}

    public String getCode() {
        return this.Code;
    }

    public void setCode(String Code) {
        this.Code = Code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create your class which will map with the output. Better read this tutorial - https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: Hi @VikasSachdeva should my class be a class containing a List of objects which contains a code and name?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for calling API -

```
Locales locales = restTemplate.getForObject(localeUrl, Locales.class, apiKey);
```

Create one `class` Locales -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Locales")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Locales{
    private List<Locale> locales = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter and setter

}
```

Comment: I have tried this and got Locales(locales=[]) when dumping out to logs.  I will update my code above

Comment: Create getter and setter method in your Locales class with public access-specifier. I wrote in answer in comment to create getter and setter. Also, your Locale class should have getter and setter

Comment: Another way is to declare fields with public access-specifier. However, it is not recommended way.

Comment: Vikas, I am using Lombok data annotation and this creates getters and setters for me

Comment: I am not aware how Lombok data annotation works, maybe you can try to manually create getter/setter OR make your fields public and use annotation @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD). It may be possible when jackson is looking for getter/setter to map json response, it is not able to find them.

Comment: I have attempted what you suggested but I am still getting a Locales(locales=[]), however when I set them all to public this seems to work fine.  I have updated my post above to reflect what I have changed in my models

Comment: So it means it is working after creating public getter/setter. This is what I suggested in comments. You can refer to this link for more details and alternative ways - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836657/jackson-1-8-0-objectmapper-to-serialize-deserialize-arbitrary-classes

Comment: Did you try removing @Data annotation and creating public getter/setter

Comment: Just read something useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779219/jackson-not-recognizing-fields-that-exist . Maybe it will help